Export blender model to unity with modifier-reliant animation
I understand that there are some posts regarding a similair topic, but none of the solutions could help with my problem in particular. I am trying to export a model with animations to unity.
The model is a pair of eyes that rotate around a sphere. The sphere is in place to ensure that the eyes rotate around a round object using the Shrinkwrap modifier.




However, when the model is exported as an fbx to unity, it moves by itself, unbound by the spherical object.

I have tried to export it without applying modifiers, and baking the animation with visual keying. I am not completely aware of how to export the model with the baked visual keying animations either.
I also apologize if this question was incoherent in any way, it is my first time asking one. Please tell me if you need more elaboration

Modifiers doesn't export in game engines (except armature). Typically, you have several options:

Recreate modifier using Unity components.
Export baked animation using shape keys or alembic file format (alembic animation doesn't work at mobile platforms)

